# RAISERROR-Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have the following code in my sql query to handle exception but it fires some error

```
Begin Catch
    If @@trancount>0
    Rollback
    Declare @errmsg nvarchar(4000), @errseverity int
    Select @errmsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @errseverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
    Raiserror(@errmsg, @errseverity, 1)
    End Catch
```

fires exception 
"Error severity levels greater than 18 can only be specified by members of the sysadmin role, using the WITH LOG option"

Comment: You could set your own severity instead of the severity of the error you caught. `16` would be a good choice.

Comment: Why not just `THROW;`?

Comment: @ TT can u please explain how...i realy dont have any idea in it

Comment: @SruthiSuresh TT means replace `@errseverity` in your RaiseError statement with simply `16` (as a suggested severity level). Maybe read the MSDN documentation on the RaiseError statement and handling in general so you understand better what is happening. The suggestion to use `THROW` is also something to try.

Comment: something to read http://sqlhints.com/2013/06/30/differences-between-raiserror-and-throw-in-sql-server/